# Serialport port fault when i work with embedded system

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to create communication with Com Ports.

I can write and read any data on my computer, but when I work with embedded system, my system doesn't read data.

My code:

```
if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
{
    serialPort1.PortName = cbComPort.SelectedItem.ToString();
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialPort1.Open();
    serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 5000;
    //serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 1500;
    serialPort1.WriteLine("USB>>READ<END");
    string gelenveri;
    bool durum = false;
    while (!durum)
    {
        try
        {
            gelenveri = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            lblGelen.Text = gelenveri;
            serialPort1.Close();
            durum = true;
            lblKarakterDeneme.Text = hextobinary(karakter_temizle(gelenveri));
            veriyerlestir(lblKarakterDeneme.Text);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Veri Alınamadı");
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The Handshake property is very important, ignoring it causes this kind of problem.  If you don't use handshaking then it is up to you to set the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to *true* yourself.  But, sounds like the device is actually using it.

Answer (score 0):

i find answer for this my question,
i canceled  serialPort1.ReadLine(); and i use SerialDataReceivedEventArgs